# Assignment of first group element - MySQL 4.7

Tags: mysql

I would like to assign the first element of a certain group to 0. The following tables are respectively the original and the final result.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
   id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   value1 INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS result (
   id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   new_col INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO t1 (id_, value1) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(3, 1),

INSERT INTO result (id_, new_col) VALUES
(1, 0),
(2, 0),
(2, 1),
(3, 0),
(3, 1)
```

Comment: How do you know which of `(2,1)` and `(2,1)` is "first" in a group?

Comment: mysql 4.7 or 5.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run so only in MySQL, in MariaDB you will need a LIMIt in the inner SELECT

The principal thing is the ORDER  of the inner SRLCT, which determines , which rownumber (rn) it will get. here i choose `ORDER BY id` to achieve your result.
But as mustachio pointed out you have to define an order, so that this will work

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
>    id_ INTEGER  NOT NULL,
>    value1 INT NOT NULL
> )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 (id_, value1) VALUES
> (1, 1),
> (2, 1),
> (2, 1),
> (3, 1),
> (3, 1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id_, value1
> FROM (SELECT
>  IF(id_ =  @id,@rn := @rn +1,@rn := 0) value1
>  ,@id :=  id_ as id_
> FROM t1,(SELECT @id := 0 ,@rn := -1) t2
> ORDER BY id_) t3
> ```
>
> ```
> id_ | value1
> --: | -----:
>   1 |      0
>   2 |      0
>   2 |      1
>   3 |      0
>   3 |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=16a29f0dee63bb7804b2d8500724ea41)*

Comment: When does the reset of @rn from 0 to -1 again occur?

Comment: in Mysql, you have to initialize the user defined @ variables, else it will not work. MySQL processes first the from clazse, where bothh variables get initialized and then it fills them row by row

Comment: What is the  variable @tn ?

Comment: only a typo of my side